# Cannot install packages: pillar, devtools. Cannot load: tidyverse, broom, etc

Tags: r, tidyverse, devtools

I am having trouble loading and installing packages on a virtual desktop. I suddenly have been getting the following errors when attempting to open the tidyverse library and others:

```
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘broom’ 0.5.6 is being loaded, but >= 0.7.6 is required
```

Then I try loading broom (which is already installed) and get this error:

```
> library(broom)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘broom’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘pillar’
```

Then I install pillar and get these messages, and pillar does not actually download.

```
> install.packages('pillar')
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘\\norc.org/home/MD/Smith-Quincey/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary source needs_compilation
pillar  1.6.0  1.6.1             FALSE

installing the source package ‘pillar’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/pillar_1.6.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1111747 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

'\\norc.org\home\MD\Smith-Quincey'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'pillar' ...
** package 'pillar' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in findpack(package, lib.loc) : there is no package called 'pillar'
Calls: <Anonymous> -> findpack
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'pillar'
* removing '\\norc.org/home/MD/Smith-Quincey/R/win-library/3.6/pillar'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\smith-quincey\AppData\Local\Temp\54\Rtmpqs7eIH\downloaded_packages’
```

I'm having a similar issue with devtools. When I attempt to install it, I get these messages:

```
> install.packages('devtools')
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘\\norc.org/home/MD/Smith-Quincey/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘remotes’, ‘rversions’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
remotes    2.3.0  2.4.0             FALSE
rversions  2.0.2  2.1.1             FALSE
devtools   2.4.1  2.4.2             FALSE

installing the source packages ‘remotes’, ‘rversions’, ‘devtools’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/remotes_2.4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 149836 bytes (146 KB)
downloaded 146 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rversions_2.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 42064 bytes (41 KB)
downloaded 41 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_2.4.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 371298 bytes (362 KB)
downloaded 362 KB

'\\norc.org\home\MD\Smith-Quincey'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'remotes' ...
** package 'remotes' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in findpack(package, lib.loc) : 
  there is no package called 'remotes'
Calls: <Anonymous> -> findpack
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'remotes'
* removing '\\norc.org/home/MD/Smith-Quincey/R/win-library/3.6/remotes'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘remotes’ had non-zero exit status
'\\norc.org\home\MD\Smith-Quincey'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'rversions' ...
** package 'rversions' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in findpack(package, lib.loc) : 
  there is no package called 'rversions'
Calls: <Anonymous> -> findpack
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'rversions'
* removing '\\norc.org/home/MD/Smith-Quincey/R/win-library/3.6/rversions'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rversions’ had non-zero exit status
'\\norc.org\home\MD\Smith-Quincey'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
ERROR: dependencies 'remotes', 'rversions' are not available for package 'devtools'
* removing '\\norc.org/home/MD/Smith-Quincey/R/win-library/3.6/devtools'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\smith-quincey\AppData\Local\Temp\54\Rtmpqs7eIH\downloaded_packages’
```

Please let me know if you have any pointers.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried installing things in R instead of RStudio? Just something easy to check that is often a workaround

Comment: When you see the message "** is being loaded, but ** is required", that means part of the package has already been loaded in the R workspace and cannot be updated in that session. Normally that means you need to exit R and restart. Make sure you aren't auto-loading any packages in a startup script. Then try `install.packages()` again. When it askes if you want to install from source, be sure to say "no". That will install the precompiled versions which are more likely not to cause trouble. You can be explicit using `install.packages(..., type="binary")`

Comment: To add to @MrFlick's comment: when you restart R, make sure you aren't in a current project that is loading a `.Rdata` file (this is closely related to the mentioned "startup script"): doing so can and will load some packages, which may not allow you to update the errant packages. If this is the case (and you are using RStudio), then start a new project in RStudio (with no `.Rdata` file), restart R, and try to install those packages *there* instead of in a project that is already depending on (and loading) these packages.

Comment: @MrFlick ,thanks so much for your comment (r2evans as well). Using the "type = "binary"" option in a fresh script solved my issues! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As the warning says, you need Rtools to install packages from source on Windows. Either install Rtools first https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/, or say no when asked if you want to install from source.